# How do I get around an error in ANTLR4 equation generation

Tags: integer, expression, antlr4

I teach compiler design at the masters level and have given my students a gcd function in their homework for a subset of C. The language has no remainder or modulus function so the equation needs to express { x - x/y * y } for integers but ANTLR4 will not build a parse tree with the '/' executing before '*' regardless of the grammar.

My grammar:

```
    exp : exp ( ( '*' | '/' ) exp)+  
        | exp ( ( '+' | '-' ) exp)+  
        | exp ( '<=' | '<' | '>' | '>=' | '==' | '!=' ) exp  
        | '(' exp ')'  
        | var | call | NUM ;
```

How should I write the grammar to get the division to be calculated before the multiplication that follows it without requiring the language to include parentheses? Is there a flag that can be set to make the honey badger do the right thing?

One of my students did the following:

```
    logic_exp : exp ( '<=' | '<' | '>' | '>=' | '==' | '!=' ) exp  
              | exp ;  
    exp       : exp ( '+' | '-' ) term | term ;  
    term      : term ( '*' | '/' ) factor |  factor ;  
    factor    : '(' logic_exp ')' | var | call | NUM ;
```

He got the right parse tree. I did not.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
exp : exp '/' exp
    | exp '*' exp
    | exp ( '+' | '-' ) exp
    | exp ( '<=' | '<' | '>' | '>=' | '==' | '!=' ) exp
    | '(' exp ')'
    | var
    | call
    | NUM
    ;
```

resulting in:

[image]

You could keep them at the same level, like Mike showed, but then input like `x - x * y / y` will give precedence to `*`. I assumed you also wanted `/` to get precedence in that case, but I might be mistaken of course :). Anyway, one of the two answers ought to get you going!

Answer (score 0):

Bart essentially showed the real problem with your grammar. You use loops for the RHS in the first 2 alts. These are not needed anyway, so by removing them like Bart did (but keeping precedence of `/` and `*` at the same level) the correct parse tree is produced.

```
    exp : exp ( '*' | '/' ) exp
        | exp ( '+' | '-' ) exp  
        | exp ('<=' | '<' | '>' | '>=' | '==' | '!=' ) exp  
        | '(' exp ')'  
        | var | call | NUM ;
```

[image]

Comment: With his version, for the input `1/2*3` , the `*` gets precedence, while `/` should get precedence over `*`

Comment: Yes, a moment later I realized that and tested more. Actually `*` and `/` have the same precedence. So your solution might also lead to trouble. The real problem is the loop on the right hand side of 3 first alts. Let me change my answer.

Comment: I removed the loop.

Comment: And you made `/` having a higher precedence than `*`. However, I'm yet trying to see if that is a real problem...

Comment: Correct, I did that because Allyn asked: "How should I write the grammar to get the division to be calculated before the multiplication [...]". I don't think my suggested change would cause problems for other expressions...